# Unable to parse the output from HTTPConnection.debuglevel

Tags: python

I am trying to programmability check the output of a tcp stream.  I am able to get the results of the tcp stream by turning on debug in HTTPConnection but how do I read the data and evaluate it with say a regular expression.  I keep getting "TypeError: expected string or buffer".  Is there a way to convert the result to a string?
thanks!

SCRIPT:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError
import urllib2
import cookielib
import httplib
import re

httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1 
p = re.compile('abc=..........')

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
proxy_address = '192.168.232.134:8083' # change the IP:PORT, this one is for example
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': proxy_address})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler, urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj), urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
url = "http://www.google.com/" # change the url
req=urllib2.Request(url)
data=urllib2.urlopen(req)
m=p.match(data)
if m:
    print "Match found."
else:
    print "Match not found."
```

RESULTS:

```
send: 'GET hyperlink/ HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/2.6\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 303 See Other\r\n'
header: Location: hyperlink:8083/3240951276
header: Set-Cookie: abc=3240951276; path=/; domain=.google.com; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-2020 23:59:59 GMT
header: Content-Length: 0
send: 'GET hyperlink/3240951276 HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: hyperlink\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/2.6\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 303 See Other\r\n'
header: Location: hyperlink
header: Set-Cookie: abc=3240951276; path=/; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-2020 23:59:59 GMT
header: Content-Length: 0
send: 'GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nCookie: abc=3240951276\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/2.6\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Date: Mon, 18 Oct 2010 21:09:32 GMT
header: Expires: -1
header: cache-control: max-age=0, private, private
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
header: Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=066bc785a2b15ef6:FF=0:TM=1287436172:LM=1287436172:S=mNiXaRhshpf8nLji; expires=Wed, 17-Oct-2012 21:09:32 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
header: Set-Cookie: NID=39=ur3gnXL80kEy4shKAh8_-XV8PhmS4G83slPcX9OD3L6uthQZw-wq7RUnB0WKGYR3F_QGoyZAyEPCvjdi69EXXq23dzvpuZSl_KU2o7pqcTB7Vym4co1LOXmi9YQGpbkb; expires=Tue, 19-Apr-2011 21:09:32 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
header: Server: gws
header: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
header: Connection: close
header: Content-Length: 4676
header: X-Con-Reuse: 1
header: Content-Encoding: gzip
header: via: 1.1 HermesPrefetch (CID2627003316.AID3240951276.TID1)
header: X-Trace-Timing: Start=1287436172845, Sched=0, Dns=2, Con=11, RxS=28, RxD=35
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\asdf\workspace\PythonScripts2\src\Test1.py", line 18, in <module>
    m=p.match(data)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Answer (score 0):

The debug information `httplib` provides you there, which you see in your terminal, is not actually part of the object returned by `urllib2.urlopen()`. Instead, it's printed directly to your process's `sys.stdout`. There's no way to change this behaviour in `httplib`, unfortunately. It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to achieve by "capturing" this output and running a regular expression over it, but if that's *really* what you want to do, you would need to replace `sys.stdout` with something else, such as a suitable `StringIO` object, and somehow seeing which output is the output you care about.

However, keep in mind that all the information that `httplib` produces in its debug output is available directly in your program. It's either based on stuff you pass to `httplib` (through `urllib2`) or it's part of the server's response, and thus available in the object returned by `urllib2.urlopen()`. For example, it looks like you're trying to extract the cookie information, which you can get at simply by getting the cookie from the `CookieJar` you're already providing. There doesn't seem to be any sensible reason to try and capture the output and parsing it.

Comment: Hi Thomas,  Thank you for your response.  It's very helpful.  The reason I want to follow the tcp "conversation"  is that I have a client in between the webserver and my browser that is acting as a proxy and I want to read the responses and follow the redirects it generates.  Is there a better way to do this?  It seems to me that the cookies that you get when you examine the cookie jar are the response cookies for the web server.  How to do you get intermediate cookies and responses programatically?  Thanks, John